# Name Entity Recognition in of own language

Tags: nlp, dataset, named-entity-recognition

I have a dataset of my native language, can I generate a Named Entity Recognition(NER) model for my language?
How should I proceed with this, Is any tutorial based on this that develops a NER model of my own language which helps to learn from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. If you have a corpus of your language, you can [train word embedding model](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-a-word2vec-model-from-scratch-with-gensim-c457d587e031), `word2vec`, and use your trained word embeddings to [train sequential models](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-using-keras-bidirectional-lstm-28cd3f301f54), e.g., `BiLSTM`. Also, if you have a very large corpus, you can even [pretrain a transformer-based model](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/pretraining_BERT/) like `BERT` to [fine-tune in your labeled NER dataset](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter7/2?fw=pt). If you don't have such corpus, you can [use `CRF` model with hand-crafted features](https://medium.com/data-science-in-your-pocket/training-custom-ner-system-using-crfs-146e0e922851), such as length of the words and whether words are titled or not etc.